# How to replace style in html with regular expressions?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have string html like this:

```
<table style="width: 630px;"></table>
```

and i need change it to

```
<table style="width: 100%;"></table>
```

I also try regular expression but i cannot change it.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What programming language are you using? Can't you just do it in a text editor?

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention language. I use PHP.

Comment: What code have you written so far to try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace `630px` then you can do `str_replace('630px', '100%', $string);`

If you need to match any `px`, you can do `preg_replace('/[0-9]+px/', '100%', $string);`

If you want to only match it where it's associated with the `width`, you'll want `preg_replace('/width\: *[0-9]+px/', 'width: 100%', $string);`

For anything more serious (only matching in the table tag, etc) you'll probably want to look into [HTML parsing](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).